# What is the proper way to stop awaited tasks when object goes out of scope?

Tags: c#, async-await, architecture

My application has two distinct states, each of them having independent set of resources, but only one of them can be active at a time.

The state is represented by a class which holds managed references to various services. For simplicity let's just assume this:

```cs
class FirstApplicationState {
  ServiceA FooService { get; }
  ServiceB BarService { get; }
}

// Some 'global' object holds reference to State
Application.State = new FirstApplicationState();
```

The `ServiceA` class during execution launches a delayed-execution task.

```cs
class ServiceA {
  CancellationTokenSource tsc;
  
  private async Task TriggerDelayedActionAsync() {
    try {
       tsc = new CancellationTokenSource();
       await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),tsc.Token);
    }
    catch(TaskCancelledException) {
      Log.Info("Task cancelled");
      return;
    }
    finally { /*dispose tsc*/ }

    await RunVeryLongTaskAsync();
  }
}
```

The task should no longer execute if the `FirstApplicationState` is no longer the active state of the application. If the state will go out of scope and the entire hierarchy will be marked to be colleced by invoking `Application.State = null` while the `Task.Delay()` method is being awaited, the instance of `ServiceA` won't be marked for GC collection, and the await will finally execute, invoking the `RunVeryLongTaskAsync` method, which will load some resources and potentially throw an exception.

To avoid it, the natural solution would be to just introduce some `Deinitialize()` method to services and  run a deinitialization process which will properly trigger all cancellation tokens before the Application allows for marking state for GC collection, although it seems like requiring tracking cancellation tokens for all potential tasks.

I'm wondering if there is some other mechanism, which would let me cancel all tasks once object executing them goes out of scope? While not relying on it for proper state cleanup, maybe I can check if any tasks on entire hierarchy of objects are still running for debugging purposes? I'm also considering using double-source cancellation tokens which would allow me for some higher level cancellation like described [in Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-listen-for-multiple-cancellation-requests), but I'm not sure how common of a practice is this as I haven't encountered similar solutions before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The task should no longer execute if the FirstApplicationState is no longer the active state of the application.

The easiest way to check this is to have the method itself check if it is still supposed to run. If you only need to check once at a particular point, that is what I would recommend.

> the instance of ServiceA won't be marked for GC collection... maybe I can check if any tasks on entire hierarchy of objects are still running for debugging purposes?

There actually is no "hierarchy". The problem is that tasks exist in memory linked in the *opposite* way of what you need. The task returned from `TriggerDelayedActionAsync` does not reference the task returned from `Task.Delay` at all. The *opposite* is actually true. The timer acts as a GC root, referencing the task returned from `Task.Delay`, which has a continuation for `TriggerDelayedActionAsync`, which references the task returned from `TriggerDelayedActionAsync`.

> To avoid it, the natural solution would be to ... trigger all cancellation tokens... although it seems like requiring tracking cancellation tokens for all potential tasks.

Yes. If you need to only check once (e.g., before the long task begins), then you can get away with a single check at that time. But if you need to be able to cancel at any time, then a [`CancellationToken` would be an appropriate solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads). Linked cancellation tokens may also be necessary, as you noted.

There's nothing built-in for this; you'll have to add those cancellation tokens everywhere if you need to support that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list tasks for debugging purposes, you can use
[TaskScheduler.GetScheduledTasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.getscheduledtasks?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_GetScheduledTasks) (You can get the default scheduler from `Scheduler.ThreadPool`)

Or [implement your own TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) and use it in a `TaskFactory`